# Multiples instances of VideoJS playlist are deprecated

Tags: wordpress, video.js, playlist, brightcove

I'm developing a Wordpress Plugin that allows users to add custom video playlists to their pages or posts, and for that I'm using Videojs and Videojs Playlist libraries.

I've successfully managed to add a single playlist into a page, but when a second one is created the first player is disabled.
[First Player disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS66d.png)

Other problem I'm facing is that, although the vjs-playlist *div* is added, it only shows in the first player created.
[Code display in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS5zC.png)

```
      var options = {"techOrder": ["html5","youtube", "flash"]};
      var myPlayer = videojs('my-playlist-player', {options, "autoplay": false, "controls": true, "fluid": true, "liveui": true});
  
      myPlayer.playlist([{
        name: 'Test item 1 type .m3u8',
        description: 'Testing for videojs-playlist-ui integration',
        duration: '45',
        sources: [
          {src: '//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4',type: 'video/mp4'}
        ],
        thumbnail: [
          {
            srcset: '//bcvid.brightcove.com/players-example-content/clouds-1800.jpg',
            type: 'image/jpeg',
            style: 'max-height: 120px;'
          }  
        ]
        },{
        name: resTitle,
        description: resDesc,
        duration: resDuration,//'45',
        sources: [
          {src: resItemSrc, type: resMime}
        ],
        thumbnail: [
          {
            srcset: resThumbnail,
            type: resImgType,
            style: thumbStyle//'max-height: 120px;'
          }  
        ]
        }
        } 
      ]);

      
      console.log(myPlayer.playlist());
      myPlayer.playlistUi({el: document.getElementById('vjs-playlist'), horizontal: true});
      myPlayer.playlist.autoadvance(1);
```

I believe my errors happen because videojs functions are detecting the same id in all elements, but if so how could I avoid this?

Any other ideas or opinions on why this errors might be happening, would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more of information, I wanted to check how many players the script detected and so I printed in the console the `window.videojs.players` and only one player is detected even if more are created. [Check result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69LxQ.png)

Could this be because they have the same ID? If so how could it be fixed? [HTML Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqVsU.png)